# parse dashboard error: You don't have any apps

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

I have created my own instance of parse-server and parse-dashboard.  The parse server is working correctly as I can read and write entries remotely via `curl`.

When I open the dashboard in my browser `http://192.168.2.28:4040/apps`, it will then ask for a username and password, which I have configured.  After a successful login, I see the error message: `You don't have any apps`.  However, parse dashboard should see one app running, named `testerdb`.  I believe I have something misconfigured, but am unsure of what this could be.

To start my parse server I am running this bash script:

```
APPID="appid123456"
MASTERKEY="masterkey654321"
DBURI="mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/testerdb?ssl=false"
APPNAME="testerdb"

parse-server --verbose --appId ${APPID} --masterKey ${MASTERKEY} --appName ${APPNAME} --databaseURI ${DBURI}
```

Again, I am able to successfully read/write to the parse app via `curl`.

To start the dashboard I am running:

```
DASH=/lib/node_modules/parse-dashboard/Parse-Dashboard/parse-dashboard-config.json
parse-dashboard --config ${DASH} --allowInsecureHTTP=1
```

The `allowInsecureHTTP` won't be used in production. I am simply using it to help troubleshoot.

This is my parse-dashboard-config.json:

```
{
  "apps": [{
    "serverURL": "http://localhost:1337/parse",
    "appId": "appid123456",
    "masterKey": "masterkey654321",
    "appName": "testerdb"
  }],
  "users": [{
    "user":"jftuga",
    "pass":"xyz789",
    "apps": [{"appId1": "appid123456"}]
  }]
}
```

Both bash scripts are running as the `parse` user. In the browser, there are no javascript console messages. In my `parse-server.info` log file (for parse-server) it does not appear that any parse-dashboard processes are accessing the app. I am also accessing the dashboard from another computer on the same LAN.

- Where/How is the dashboard looking for running apps?
- What log files can I look at in order to troubleshoot?
- What else can I do to debug this?

[image: dashboard screenshot]

Comment: did you allow required ports in firewall?

Comment: @MazelTov: I checked that and it was not a firewall issue.  I did find a solution.  See my full answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were **2** problems with the above configuration.

**Issue 1**

My `parse-dashboard-config.json` was located in `/lib/node_modules/parse-dashboard/Parse-Dashboard` but actually needed to be in `/lib/node_modules/parse-dashboard/Parse-Dashboard/public`. Notice the `/public` at the end.

**Issue 2**

The line:

```
"serverURL": "http://localhost:1337/parse",
```

needs to be:

```
"serverURL": "http://192.168.1.28:1337/parse",
```

as this URL will be accessed by the browser's Javascript code.  Therefore, it needs to be an externally accessible IP address.

Comment: as for the **Issue 2**, it is not true, my parse dashboard is running on localhost, maybe you have some firewall issue :-)

Comment: also the Issue 1 is wrong, I am running parse-dashboard with this command `parse-dashboard --config /home/parse/dashboard-config.json` and it is laso running only on http because I alway create ssh tunnel to my machine so it is kind of SSL encryption too...

Comment: @Mazel: Thank you for downvoting.  As for your previous comment, you mention "I alway [sic] create ssh tunnel...".  It's too bad the question was trying to solve the problem for MY environment and not yours. "Kind of SSL encryption" does not make sense. Either it is or it is not.

Comment: I was refering to `as this URL will be accessed by the browser's Javascript code. Therefore, it needs to be an externally accessible IP address.` and **it is not true**, and for the issue 1, when you are calling argument `--config` and write the wrong path there and asking question here, that is just hilarious :-D

Answer (score 0):

Your parse dashboard is unable to get the right data from the configuration file you're setting for it. I advice if possible to do this

```
import 'dotenv/config';
const express = require('express');
const ParseDashboard = require('parse-dashboard');

const dashboard = new ParseDashboard({
    "apps": [
        {
            "serverURL": process.env.SERVER_URL,
            "appId": process.env.APP_ID,
            "masterKey": process.env.MASTER_KEY,
            "appName": process.env.APPNAME,
        }
    ]
});

const app = express();

// make the Parse Dashboard available at /dashboard
app.use('/dashboard', dashboard);

const httpServer = require('http').createServer(app);
httpServer.listen(4040);
```

And then start as a script like this

> yarn parse-dashboard

or

> npm run parse-dashboard